Understanding a proof that a uniformly Cauchy sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_n$ converges uniformly to a limit function $f$
Suppose $\{f_n\}_n$ is a uniformly Cauchy sequence of continuous function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to S$ for a complete metric space $S$. I am trying to understand the "standard" proof that the sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ converges uniformly to its limit function. The overall argument is something along the lines of:

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq m\geq N_\varepsilon$ we have $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:d_S(f_n(x),f_m(x)) < \varepsilon$. Now pointwise for any $x\in X$, using the fact that $d_S(.,.)$ is continuous in both of its arguments, we may take the limit as $n\to \infty$ to conclude that


$$\varepsilon \geq \lim_{n\to\infty}d_S(f_n(x), f_m(x)) = d_S(f(x), f_m(x))$$


Since this holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ it follows that $\{f_n\}_n$ converges uniformly to $f$.

My gripe with the argument is that I would very much like to see how it is handled in the uniform norm, $\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}d_S(f(x), f_n(x))$. I don't know how to do this my self. We can start by estimating
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}}d_S(f(x), f_n(x))\leq \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}d_S(f(x), f_m(x)) + \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}d_S(f_m(x), f_n(x))$$
where the first summand can be taken to be less than $\varepsilon$ by hypothesis with all $n,m$ large enough. But a priori convergence to $f$ happens pointwise, and so I'm not sure how to "choose" some new $M\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough that we can conclude that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}d_S(f_m(x), f_n(x)) < \varepsilon$$
So how should the argument be treated/altered?

It sounds like your problem is actually with the first summand. If I am not mistaken, the existence of a uniform $M$ for the second term comes from being uniformly Cauchy.

@Keen-ameteur Yeah sorry, I had originally written the arguments of the metric the other way around, and so by "second" I really meant "first", like you said. In any case, do you know how to deal with the first summand?

Are you looking for a proof or just a hint?

First note that in order for $d_{\infty}(f,g) = \sup_{t \in \mathbb R} d_Y(f(t),g(t))$ to be a metric one must work with the space $\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R, Y)$ of all bounded continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to the complete metric space $Y$.
Once you do that, however, the standard proof does provide what you want, if you are careful: If $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy seqeunce in $(\mathcal C_b(\mathbb R, Y), d_{\infty})$ where $Y$ is a complete metric space, then for all $t\in \mathbb R$, we have $d_Y(f_n(t),f_m(t) \leq d_{\infty}(f_n,f_m) \to 0$ as $n,m \to \infty$, so that $(f_n(t))_{n \geq 1}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $Y$, which therefore, by the completeness of $Y$, converges to some element of $Y$ which we denote by $f(t)$. Thus we see that, by construction, $f_n \to f$ pointwise.
Next one has to show that $f_n \to f$ with respect to the metric $d_{\infty}$, i.e. uniformly, not just pointwise. If $\epsilon >0$ then since $(f_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy, there is an $N>0$ such that if $n,m \geq N$ then $d_\infty(f_n,f_m) < \epsilon$. The following claim establishes that $f_n \to f$ uniformly:
Claim: $d_\infty(f_n,f)\leq \epsilon$.
Proof: It suffices to show that $d_{\infty}(f_n,f)<\epsilon+\delta$ for any positive $\delta$. For this, note that for all $t \in \mathbb R$ we have
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
d_S(f_n(t),f(t)) \leq d_S(f_n(t),f_m(t)) + d_S(f_m(t),f(t))
$$
and since by construction $d_S(f_m(t),f(t))\to 0$ as $m \to \infty$, there is some $M_t \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $d_S(f_m(t),f(t))<\delta/2$ for all $m \geq M_t$. Thus taking $m=M_t$ in ($\dagger$) we find
$$
\begin{split}
d_S(f_n(t),f(t)) &\leq d_S(f_n(t),f_{M_t}(t)) + d_S(f_{M_t}(t),f(t))\\
&\leq d_{\infty}(f_n,f_{M_t}) + d_S(f_{M_t}(t),f(t)) \\
&<\epsilon +\delta/2.
\end{split}
$$
But now we have shown that if $n \geq N$ then for all $t \in \mathbb R$ we have $d_S(f_n(t),f(t))<\epsilon+\delta/2$ hence $d_\infty(f_n,f) \leq \epsilon +\delta/2 < \epsilon+\delta$ as required.
